# Simple HTML dom parser for multiple URLs

Tags: php, html, dom

I'm parsing fine from one url, but how do i add a second source url in the same file.

e.g.

```
$html = file_get_html('http://google.com');
```

for one url, but how to add second source and make it work with "echo" function?

Thanks

Comment: What is 'make it work with "echo" function' supposed to mean?

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think most parsers will let you add invalid duplicated tags like `<head>` and `<body>`. You could try by first parsing both URLs and extracting their bodies:

```
$page1 = file_get_html('url1');
$body1 = $page1->find('body');

$page2 = file_get_html('url2');
$body2 = $page2->find('body');
```

Then get them together and parse back:

```
$body1 = $body1->plaintext;
$body2 = $body2->plaintext;
$bodies = str_get_html($body1.$body2);
```